# MySQL metadata (usage and performance statistics)

Tags: mysql, database, database-performance, database-metadata

I am working on a web application that is based on a MySQL database. I need to collect and analyse usage and performance statistics. The statistics will be aimed at non-technical personnel.

How can I implement this feature? You should treat my question as a programming question but in case you know of a tool or extension that would be suitable please mention it.

Comment: MySQL itself has Performance Schema since version 5.5.3 and [Slow Query Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/slow-query-log.html). Read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/performance-schema.html)

Comment: @Raptor I am looking for a (hopefully already implemented) solution to present such metadata to a non-technical user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official MySQL client, MySQL Workbench includes the feature to visualize Performance Schema since version 6.1. It's in Performance section in the software.

Read more at: http://mysqlworkbench.org/